# Could I use UNION in a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables that I user every day (don't bother with the names, those are examples):

- books
- shelves
- notes

For some reason I had to create antoher tables for archiving. So there are archive_books, archive_shelves and archive_notes.

There is a "search" interface in the application and sometimes I would like to search in archive tables. However in the result I have to display datas from all 3 tables. Because anybody can search I have to run the query in both tables (archive and normal).

Searching without archive tables could run like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books b
LEFT JOIN shelves s ON s.id = b.shelf_id
LEFT JOIN notices n ON n.book_id = b.id
WHERE smt="%search_query%";
```

Archiving a shelf means all books put to the given shelf and all notice refer to a book in the given shelf copies over to archive tables and deleting from source table.

So, could searching in archive and non-archive tables look like this?

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM books UNION SELECT * FROM archive_books) b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM shelves UNION SELECT * FROM archive_shelves) s ON s.id = b.shelf_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM notices UNION SELECT * FROM archive_notices) n ON n.book_id = b.id
WHERE smt="%search_query%";
```

I hope I could write my quiestion properly! :)

Comment: Have you tried it?  If so, did you have any difficulties?  SO isn't a place for `Does this code work?`, that much you should be able to answer for yourself, even using sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: Nope, I don't know whether SQL allows it. I've checked [JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) but I just read "table references" and "table factor" and I don't know whether my code satisfies it.

Comment: Are `shelf_id` and `book_id` values unique in both tables ? If no, the query may return garbage, because may join "not archived" books with "archived shelves" and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, if you would merge those two tables there would no duplicate keys. I was copying with this command: `INSERT INTO archive_books SELECT * FROM books WHERE [condition]`

Comment: If these tables don't contain duplicate keys, then this query is pretty fine. Unless these tables are huge, they contain a lot of records and you are worrying about the performance. How many books and shelves are stored in the database ?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do that, however I'd want to look at the query plan to see how efficient it is.
One alternative is to create a view for each pair:

```
create view AllBooks as select * from books union select * from archiveBooks;
```

..and then use the view in your search queries.

Cheers -